# Struts2 to show wait page only on some condition

Tags: struts2

My application using struts 2.3.24.1 and it needs to show wait page only if variable in my action is "ABC" else my application should not show a wait page .

I have tried using interceptor  - `execAndWait` for this , however it enables for complete action . I just want wait page to be shown only in some cases .

How can i achieve this without using `execAndWait` interceptor?

Comment: How come the variable in your action get initialized?

Comment: Very unclear. What are you trying to do? Why not to simple show appropriate page?

Comment: I think you can use strut's `<s:if` tag.